# Impossible to get answer from local http server

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote simple http server that accept get request and return data. Data are accessable from browser.

The problem with Flutter app. I can't get result in: `http.get().then` when I am trying to get access to my local web server. But When I am changing it to public it's work.

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  build(Build) {
    return Column(
      children: [
      WorkersSlider(),
      RaisedButton(onPressed: () =>  {
      
      print("sdfsfd"),
      http.get('https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts',
      // http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/status',
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          "Access-Control_Allow_Origin": "*"
        }
      ).then((value) => {
        print("1111113"),
        print("value from parser: $value")
      }),
      
      } ),

      
    ],);
  }

}
```

server code:

```
main() async {
  const int PORT = 5000;
  var app = express();
  app.use(BodyParser.json());

  app.get('/status', (req, res) async {
      print("status request");
      List jobsAsList = [];
      for(var job in jobsList) 
      {
        // jobs generation logic is skipped
        jobsAsList.add(job.toJson());
      }
      res.json({'data': jobsAsList});

  });

  app.listen(port: PORT, cb: (int port) => print('Listening on port $port'));

}
```

curl works:

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/status
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   279    0   279    0     0   272k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  272k{"data":[{"jobPid":13772,"job_cmd":null,"jobStatus":null,"lastPingDate":"2021-01-25T14:53:47.000"},{"jobPid":8544,"job_cmd":null,"jobStatus":null,"lastPingDate":"2021-01-25T14:53:47.000"},{"jobPid":18156,"job_cmd":null,"jobStatus":null,"lastPingDate":"2021-01-25T14:53:47.000"}]}
```

Any ideas?

UPD: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/433

Answer (score 0):

Im editing my answer, I didn't understood your problem at first.

If you're using a Android Emulator to test this code, this is probably a problem with your localhost.

The localhost of your PC, isn't the same localhost as your emulator since Android Emulator run in Virtual Machines.

Try editing your endpoint URL to http://10.0.2.2:5000/status

Comment: Thanks! But as you see on screenshot there is no even string above. And on your code I got: `The getter 'data' isn't defined for the class 'Response'.`

Comment: `.body` should be. But still not print string that above it.

Comment: I am using flutter for web. So I do not think that issue can be with wrong endpoint. At last I can open it in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since Response is class that contains multiple fields should get value from response like 'response.body'.

In your exact case `print("value from parser: ${value.body}")`.

Comment: But I can't get to print even `1111113`

Comment: In your screenshot there is printed 1111113. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: on left where I am accessing to my local server -- no.